# MySQL: update field with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

this is an example:

table mysql schema :

```
 id   name   salary
 1    david   20 
 2    jack    30
 3    david   10
```

**Query:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET salary = salary  + 5 WHERE name = 'david' ";
```

I want to added `Group By name` to avoid duplicate update for `david`
How Could I do that?

Comment: What row will you update, 1 or 3 in your example?

Comment: Do you want to update both rows or just one of them? If so, you'd need to use a different query by using the `id` and not `name`.

Comment: This doesn't even make sense. How would GROUP BY define which `david` you're referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using LIMIT, which is an extension to SQL used by MySQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET salary = salary  + 5 WHERE name = 'david' 
        ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
```

It makes no sense to use GROUP BY, because it would be ambiguous whether to update the first row in the group, or the last row, or all of the rows.  MySQL does not support a GROUP BY clause in the UPDATE statement.